# Operating System isn't working in Onda V812

Tags: updates, 4.1-jelly-bean, hard-reset

I bought an Onda V812, a Chinese tablet. Since beginning, the operating system hasn't worked correctly.

Now it simply doesn't boot. I'd like to reset the tablet and maybe install a new version of Android to see if it works.  The Onda V812 specifications are very good so I'd like to believe that there should be a solution to my problem.

My e-mail complaints to their support team have not been replied.

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: When you say the tablet will not boot does that mean that nothing happens when you hold down the power button? Or does it start to boot but freezes on the Android screen, never reaching the lock screen?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried holding down the power button and the volume up button at the same time until you see the dead android and red triangle, if you then tap the volume up button once you should see a list of options including factory reset(complete data removal) which will reset the device to the basic state it was in when you bought it